# apache solr 5.3.0 search in multiple core

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I am using solr 5.3.0 , I have 6 core. schema of all 6 core is same. now I want to search query in all 6 core at one time. Is there any way to do it? I am using php solarium. It will be really helpful is anyone can share small example code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this kind of queries if you use SolrCloud in which you can have a single collection with multiple shards. You can either query selected shards or the entire collection.

And while updating a collection with a document, the document gets indexed in any one of the shard based on router and router.field values.

Note that generally SolrCloud is used for distributed search. And collection in SolrCloud is like a core in Solr.